# Given an `RDF::Term` from the `RDF::Vocab` library, how do I infer the XSD datatype(s) I should expect?

Tags: ruby, xsd, rdf

I'm using Ruby scripts to to round-trip a SKOS vocabulary definition in Turtle format through to a spreadsheet (via CSV) and back to allow non-technical people to check and update the localised phrases. This then needs to be converted back into the Turtle format with as little non-significant churn and variation from the original as possible.

The spreadsheet has these columns (for the sake of this example):

- vocab ID
- term ID
- property ID
- value
- EN
- FR
- ...

`vocab ID` contains an abbreviated URI for the vocabulary, e.g. `foo:bar`.

`property ID` contains abbreviated URIs identifying a property of either the vocabulary itself or a term in it. (such as `dcterm:created` or `dc:title` for the former case; or `skos:prefName` or `skos:altLabel` for the latter).  A special case of the former is `base_uri`, defining the vocab's base URI.

`term ID` contains IDs identifying a term in the vocabulary when appropriate - or it is blank for properties of the vocabulary itself.

`value` is an unlocalised string literal, or some other sort of literal (like a date), or an URI, as appropriate. It may be blank if the value is a localised string - the other columns then contain the translated versions of the property in various languages. The column name is the two-letter identifier for the language.

Creating the CSV is not the problem - what is a little tricky is reading back the literal values and recreating the correct literal values.

Here's the thing: I'd like to be able to infer the XSD datatype of the property from the [RDF::Term](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/ruby-rdf/rdf/RDF/Term) for it. I can look the latter up from the abbreviated URI, using [RDF::Vocab](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/rdf-vocab). However there seems to be no mapping I can find in these libraries to the XSD datatype (whether mandatory or merely suggested.)

This seems to mean I must create a mapping from property IDs to the XSD datatype myself if I'm to avoid ending up with all the values becoming string literals by default (which wouldn't preserve the original datatypes).

Can anyone advise if I'm correct here, or is there a way to infer the nominal XSD datatype to use using the [Ruby RDF](https://github.com/ruby-rdf) libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean an `RDF::Vocabulary::Term` instance, which typically is an IRI, but contains accessors for a related vocabulary definition.

The [Documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/ruby-rdf/rdf/RDF/Vocabulary/Term) for `RDF::Vocabulary::Term` describes the generic accessors you can use, and for a term based on a property, you might look at either `range` or `rangeIncludes` accessors to get an idea of what the preferred values that might be used as the object of a triple using this term.

The built-in vocabularies are minimal, pretty much limited to RDF, RDFS, XSD, and OWL. Load the `rdf-vocab` gem, and many other vocabularies are loaded. You can also use the [`RDF::Vocabulary.from_graph`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/ruby-rdf/rdf/RDF/Vocabulary#from_graph-class_method) class method to instantiate a new vocabulary, including its term definitions, from a graph.

For example, see the following:

```rb
require 'rdf/vocab'

RDF::Vocab::SCHEMA.name.rangeIncludes # => [RDF::Vocab::SCHEMA.Text]

RDF::Vocab::FOAF.name.range # => [RDF::RDFS.Literal]
```

Other common accessors correspond to basic RDFS, OWL, SKOS, and schema.org annotation properties. Or, you can access an arbitrary annotation property using `#attribute_value` and `#properties` accessors.

In some cases, property range may be more complex, take for example, the term definition for `skos:member`:

```rb
    property :member,
      definition: "Relates a collection to one of its members.".freeze,
      domain: "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Collection".freeze,
      isDefinedBy: "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core".freeze,
      label: "has member".freeze,
      range: term(
          type: "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class".freeze,
          unionOf: list("http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept".freeze, "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Collection".freeze)
        ),
      type: ["http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property".freeze, "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#ObjectProperty".freeze]
```

Additionally, the `rdf-reasoner` gem can form entailments over vocabularies to provide additional domain and range (and other) information based on subProperty hierarchies (as well as class hierarchies for `rdf:type`).

Comment: Thanks, helpful. Calling `#range` for the term `RDF::Vocab::DC.created.range`  (f.e.) does indeed return http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal. But there's no hint that it should, or even could, be interpreted as a date (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date ?). With no other clues, this would lead to a CSV value `2021-12-25` being interpreted is a plain `#Literal` string.

Comment: (Aside: maybe encoding the value in CSV using something signifying date-ness, like `"2021-12-24"^^xsd:date`, or adding a type column, could be used to infer the type, but I'd rather avoid things which make the CSV more complicated and/or fragile for user editing.)

Comment: Investigating RDF::Reasoner, I can find the super-properties of f.e. `RDF::Vocab::DC.creator`, using `#entail`, but it's not obvious how to write code to validate and/or parse an unadorned string value as the most relevant sort of literal for an arbitrary property value (without adding extra information inferred by my own reading/guesswork). I wonder if this is a deliberate limitation of RDF vocab specs?

Comment: Dublin Core tends to not be very expressive in property domains or ranges, so while it makes sense that dc:created would be a date (or dateTime) they don’t put that in the ontology. This is actually a good use case for A ShEx or SHACL data shape, depending on your application.

Comment: The Reasoner will validate property values, but only based on their stated range and domain definitions. There is code to validate all relevant data types (XSD and Schema), but only based on ontology definitions.